# Why sould one init a react-native project with npx?

Tags: react-native, npm, npx

Today I tried to do things differently, and launched a react-native project with npx, and went into troubleshooting issues like react-native command not found, are you sure this is an android project, etc. while things were easier with expo and react-native init.

So I'm wondering, according to you, what are the advantages, what does npx more ?

Answer (score 0):

npm:
npm create-react-app my-app executes the local create-react-app package from your machine, so you first have to install it globally on your system with npm install -g create-react-app.

npx:
If you run npx create-react-app my-app and don’t have create-react-app globally on your system, it will get downloaded and not installed globally.

As you are getting "react-native command not found", first make sure to have react-native cli installed globally. For that,
`npm i -g react-native-cli`
Then create your react-native project.